# Error (the number of elements in B and I must be the same)

Tags: matlab

```
p=3;
L=1000;
x=rand(1,L);
r=zeros(p,1);
W=ones(p,L);
V=zeros(L,1);
 for k=1:L 
    r=[x(k);r(1:p-1)];
    V(k) = W.'*r;
 end
```

> I want to find the value of V(k) which is the result of transpose W times r but I'm getting the above error. would you please tell me how to fix the code to avoid that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual error is:

```
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.
```

It is because on this line `V(k) = W.'*r;`   `W.'*r` is a `100x1` double and `V(k)` is just a `1x1` number. Perhaps you meant:

```
V(:, k) = W.'*r;
```

Comment: why when I change W from W=ones(p,L) to W= ones(p,1) the code run well without any error.

Comment: @Rock Because then you have a matrix multiplication of a `1xp * px1` which results in a `1x1` which fits in your `V(k)` assignment.